# How to grab tinymce wordcount value? Currently, there is a wordcount plug in but I need to grab the value from the path

Tags: tinymce, word-count

Need to grab `tinymce wordcount` value. Currently, the `tinymce` has `wordcount` plugins and show the word count at the bottom. How do I grab this value?

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this code:

```
 var count = tinyMCE.activeEditor.plugins["wordcount"].getCount();
```